# hide section labels in listview

Tags: android, listview, sections

I use component android-section-list (http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/) to create sections in my listView. How can I hide sections after push some button?

I try to do like

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sortTitle:
                     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(
                     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                     View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.market_list_separator, null, false);
                     TextView separatorLayout = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.section_view);
                      separatorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      sectionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                setButtonState(sortByTitle);
                adapter.sort((Comparator<SectionListItem>) sortByTitle());
                break;

        }

    }
```

But this way don't work.

---

My adapter put data in list rows and SectionListAdapter draw sections.

```
public class SectionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter,
        OnItemClickListener {
    private final DataSetObserver dataSetObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            updateSessionCache();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            super.onInvalidated();
            updateSessionCache();
        };
    };

    private final ListAdapter linkedAdapter;
    private final Map<Integer, String> sectionPositions = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> itemPositions = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    private final Map<View, String> currentViewSections = new HashMap<View, String>();
    private int viewTypeCount;
    protected final LayoutInflater inflater;

    private View transparentSectionView;

    private OnItemClickListener linkedListener;

    public SectionListAdapter(final LayoutInflater inflater,
            final ListAdapter linkedAdapter) {
        this.linkedAdapter = linkedAdapter;
        this.inflater = inflater;
        linkedAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(dataSetObserver);
        updateSessionCache();
    }

    private boolean isTheSame(final String previousSection,
            final String newSection) {
        if (previousSection == null) {
            return newSection == null;
        } else {
            return previousSection.equals(newSection);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void updateSessionCache() {
        int currentPosition = 0;
        sectionPositions.clear();
        itemPositions.clear();
        viewTypeCount = linkedAdapter.getViewTypeCount() + 1;
        String currentSection = null;
        final int count = linkedAdapter.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final SectionListItem item = (SectionListItem) linkedAdapter
                    .getItem(i);
            if (!isTheSame(currentSection, item.section)) {
                sectionPositions.put(currentPosition, item.section);
                currentSection = item.section;
                currentPosition++;
            }
            itemPositions.put(currentPosition, i);
            currentPosition++;
        }
    }


    public synchronized int getCount() {
        return sectionPositions.size() + itemPositions.size();
    }


    public synchronized Object getItem(final int position) {
        if (isSection(position)) {
            return sectionPositions.get(position);
        } else {
            final int linkedItemPosition = getLinkedPosition(position);
            return linkedAdapter.getItem(linkedItemPosition);
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean isSection(final int position) {
        return sectionPositions.containsKey(position);
    }

    public synchronized String getSectionName(final int position) {
        if (isSection(position)) {
            return sectionPositions.get(position);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        if (isSection(position)) {
            return sectionPositions.get(position).hashCode();
        } else {
            return linkedAdapter.getItemId(getLinkedPosition(position));
        }
    }

    protected Integer getLinkedPosition(final int position) {
        return itemPositions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
        if (isSection(position)) {
            return viewTypeCount - 1;
        }
        return linkedAdapter.getItemViewType(getLinkedPosition(position));
    }

    private View getSectionView(final View convertView, final String section) {
        View theView = convertView;
        if (theView == null) {
            theView = createNewSectionView();
        }
        setSectionText(section, theView);
        replaceSectionViewsInMaps(section, theView);
        return theView;
    }

    protected void setSectionText(final String section, final View sectionView) {
        final TextView textView = (TextView) sectionView.findViewById(R.id.listTextView);
        textView.setText(section);
    }

    protected synchronized void replaceSectionViewsInMaps(final String section,
            final View theView) {
        if (currentViewSections.containsKey(theView)) {
            currentViewSections.remove(theView);
        }
        currentViewSections.put(theView, section);
    }

    protected View createNewSectionView() {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_view, null);
    }


    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (isSection(position)) {
            return getSectionView(convertView, sectionPositions.get(position));
        }
        return linkedAdapter.getView(getLinkedPosition(position), convertView,
                parent);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return viewTypeCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return linkedAdapter.hasStableIds();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return linkedAdapter.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(final DataSetObserver observer) {
        linkedAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(final DataSetObserver observer) {
        linkedAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return linkedAdapter.areAllItemsEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(final int position) {
        if (isSection(position)) {
            return true;
        }
        return linkedAdapter.isEnabled(getLinkedPosition(position));
    }

    public void makeSectionInvisibleIfFirstInList(final int firstVisibleItem) {
        final String section = getSectionName(firstVisibleItem);
        // only make invisible the first section with that name in case there
        // are more with the same name
        boolean alreadySetFirstSectionIvisible = false;
        for (final Entry<View, String> itemView : currentViewSections
                .entrySet()) {
            if (itemView.getValue().equals(section)
                    && !alreadySetFirstSectionIvisible) {
                itemView.getKey().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                alreadySetFirstSectionIvisible = true;
            } else {
                itemView.getKey().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        for (final Entry<Integer, String> entry : sectionPositions.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey() > firstVisibleItem + 1) {
                break;
            }
            setSectionText(entry.getValue(), getTransparentSectionView());
        }
    }

    public synchronized View getTransparentSectionView() {
        if (transparentSectionView == null) {
            transparentSectionView = createNewSectionView();
        }
        return transparentSectionView;
    }

    protected void sectionClicked(final String section) {
        //
    }


    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView< ? > parent, final View view,
            final int position, final long id) {
        if (isSection(position)) {
            sectionClicked(getSectionName(position));
        } else if (linkedListener != null) {
            linkedListener.onItemClick(parent, view,
                    getLinkedPosition(position), id);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener linkedListener) {
        this.linkedListener = linkedListener;
    }
}
```

Where can I put check for visibility in this Adapter?

Comment: Remove the section that should be hidden from the `sectionPositions` collection and call the `notifyDataSetChanged` method in the adapter. Also your adapter is quite complex, I displayed sections in much more simple way: https://github.com/vortexwolf/2ch-Browser/blob/development/src/com/vortexwolf/dvach/adapters/BoardsListAdapter.java

Answer (score 0):

This works but will be overwritten by the getView() method in the adapter . You must handle this in the adapter bcoz each time view becomes visible on the screen the  View is updated so becomes visible in your case.

For the Data you are storing add a Visibility field ( by default keep it visible ) and change the Visibility to GONE in the onClick() method.

if you dont understand , post me your code and will let you know what changes to make.

Comment: it must be in my adapter or SectionListAdapter from component?

Comment: i really cant say by less details because i don't know the details of your adapter . But whichever adapter where you are adding the sections should do the job.